# How to modify routing pattern before {controller} to handle multiple languages in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, routes, design-patterns

In ASP.NET core, I created a simple Controller and Action with the default routing

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}" });


public class Test1Controller:Controller
{
    public string HelloAct()
    {
        return "Hello World.";
    }
}
```

https://localhost:port/Test1/HelloAct
It is OK, shows  "Hello World."

I want to handle multiple languages with URL like Microsoft web site.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Add language name after domain, if the parameter is omitted, I wish it will go to "en-us".

I tried below, modified routing pattern:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{lang=en-us}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}" });

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{lang?}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}" });
```

Input: https://localhost:port/Test1/HelloAct
but neither is right. Returns 404 not found.

How to modify the routing pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You could try as below:

```
    app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{lang=en-us}/{controller=Test1}/{action=HelloAct}");

    app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "another",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{lang=en-us}");
```

sections  like `{lang=en-us}/{controller=Test1}/{action=HelloAct}` will perform as below:

> Next, the accepted values can be used to expand the route template.
> The route template is processed:
>
> From left-to-right. Each parameter has its accepted value substituted.
> With the following special cases:  If the accepted values is missing a
> value and the parameter has a default value, the default value is
> used.
>
> If the accepted values is missing a value and the parameter is
> optional, processing continues.   If any route parameter to the right
> of a missing optional parameter has a value, the operation fails.
> Contiguous default-valued parameters and optional parameters are
> collapsed where possible.

Check this part of [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#url-generation-process) carefully

with the first partten, you could access your target action with:

`"/"` or `"/en-us"` or `"/en-us/Test1"` or `"/en-us/Test1/hellowAction"`

but when you try with `"/Test1/hellowAction"`,in fact,it would go to `"/Test1/HellowAction/HellowAction"`

What i've tried :
[image]

[image]

[image]